# unable to customize houzez theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, themes

I have a Real-Estate website and installed the Houzez theme,There is a search form field and the options are Type, Location, Min pirce etc....
The problem is the type and the location field shows as a line vertically like the picture below:
[My website Type Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fILyW.jpg)
But i want to make it like this:
[My desire Type Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j9EF.jpg)...
I tried adding custom css by the type sections id and class even added js but nothing seems to work. Any idea how to do this?
This is the code for the Type div

```
<div class="elementor-field-group elementor-column form-group elementor-field-group-95424d9 elementor-col-25">
                <label for="form-field-95424d9" class="elementor-field-label elementor-screen-only">Type</label>        <div class="elementor-field elementor-select-wrapper">
        <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select houzez-field-textual form-control elementor-size-sm"><select data-live-search="true" data-size="5" name="type[]" id="form-field-95424d9" class="selectpicker houzez-field-textual form-control elementor-size-sm" data-none-results-text="No results matched {0}" tabindex="null">
            <option value="">Type</option><option data-ref="commercial" value="commercial">Commercial</option><option data-ref="apartment-commercial" value="apartment-commercial"> - Apartment</option><option data-ref="building" value="building"> - Building</option><option data-ref="duplex" value="duplex"> - Duplex</option><option data-ref="factory" value="factory"> - Factory</option><option data-ref="floor" value="floor"> - Floor</option><option data-ref="office" value="office"> - Office</option><option data-ref="plaza" value="plaza"> - Plaza</option><option data-ref="plot" value="plot"> - Plot</option><option data-ref="shop" value="shop"> - Shop</option><option data-ref="warehouse" value="warehouse"> - Warehouse</option><option data-ref="residential" value="residential">Residential</option><option data-ref="apartment" value="apartment"> - Apartment</option><option data-ref="building-residential" value="building-residential"> - Building</option><option data-ref="duplex-residential" value="duplex-residential"> - Duplex</option><option data-ref="penthouse" value="penthouse"> - Penthouse</option><option data-ref="plaza-residential" value="plaza-residential"> - Plaza</option><option data-ref="plot-residential" value="plot-residential"> - Plot</option><option data-ref="room" value="room"> - Room</option>            </select><button type="button" tabindex="-1" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-light bs-placeholder" data-toggle="dropdown" role="combobox" aria-owns="bs-select-5" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="false" data-id="form-field-95424d9" title="Type"><div class="filter-option"><div class="filter-option-inner"><div class="filter-option-inner-inner">Type</div></div> </div></button><div class="dropdown-menu" style="max-height: 257px; overflow: hidden;"><div class="bs-searchbox"><input type="search" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-label="Search" aria-controls="bs-select-5" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-activedescendant="bs-select-5-0"></div><div class="inner show" role="listbox" id="bs-select-5" tabindex="-1" style="max-height: 205px; overflow-y: auto;"><ul class="dropdown-menu inner show" role="presentation" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><li class="selected active"><a role="option" class="dropdown-item active selected" id="bs-select-5-0" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="1" aria-selected="true"><span class="text">Type</span></a></li><li class=""><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-1" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="2"><span class="text">Commercial</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-2" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="3"><span class="text"> - Apartment</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-3" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="4"><span class="text"> - Building</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-4" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="5"><span class="text"> - Duplex</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-5" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="6"><span class="text"> - Factory</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-6" tabindex="0"><span class="text"> - Floor</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-7" tabindex="0"><span class="text"> - Office</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-8" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="9"><span class="text"> - Plaza</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-9" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="10"><span class="text"> - Plot</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-10" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="11"><span class="text"> - Shop</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-11" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="12"><span class="text"> - Warehouse</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-12" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="13"><span class="text">Residential</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-13" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="14"><span class="text"> - Apartment</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-14" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="15"><span class="text"> - Building</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-15" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="16"><span class="text"> - Duplex</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-16" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="17"><span class="text"> - Penthouse</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-17" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="18"><span class="text"> - Plaza</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-18" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="19"><span class="text"> - Plot</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-19" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="20" aria-posinset="20"><span class="text"> - Room</span></a></li></ul></div></div></div>
    </div>
                        </div>
```

I tried to add custom css and javascript but it stays the same. Also tried to add code from Theme file editor of wordpress but couldn't find anything related Type dropdown or the section i need to add or modify the code .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be by editing this file you can achieve what you want

template-parts > search > fields > type.php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much sir finally, I was able to edit the type section.